# Android Transparent Screen to detect gestures from any screen

Tags: android

Is there anyway to create a transparent screen that detects gestures so that from any screen I can execute commands. This mean I can be on any application and if I do a certain gesture something will execute.

I have a main activity which will turn on and off a service and I have created a service which creates a transparent screen. Right now, I can't tap on anything behind the clear screen and can't find anything on this subject.

Is this doable or am I wasting my time?

:edited:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't doable. There is no way to create a window that can intercept touch events before they are dispatched to another application's window. If it were possible this would be a major security vulnerability.

Comment: Is my only option to create a clear side bar of some sort which opens a window to execute gesture on?

Comment: Yeah. If it were possible to create a fullscreen window to listen for touch events, then applications would be able to do a ton of crazy stuff (for example, they could create windows on top of the keyboard and estimate the characters the user types, etc.). Some sort of swipe-able drawer window coming out from the side of the screen sounds like a less impossible solution to me. :)